# Weblogic Help Error

Tags: weblogic

I have installed weblogic, in production mode , and set up custom Identity and Trust keystores using keytool. Everything seems fine.

However, whenever I call external webservices over SSL or even going to help pages in weblogic console will results in the following error

> java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Error constructing implementation (algorithm: Default, provider: SunJSSE, class: com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.DefaultSSLContextImpl)

Pls kindly assist. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

WebLogic uses certicom as the SSL provider by default. On version 10.3.3, they've added JSSE support. I haven't seen this specific error you're seeing, but maybe enabling JSSE will resolve it for you. You configure it at the server level, under Server > Configuration > SSL tab > Advanced tab

Comment: Adding on to Gustavo, You may also look to install JCE. We require ,more information. Please provide the weblogic version, java version, complete stack trace, apache log entries if you are using any, browser name and its version. What application are you accessing through SSL? Console or anything else? Please provide all these and it would be easy to help.

Answer (score 0):

You can try enabling debug for ssl to capture more information.
 -Dssl. debug=true and -Dweblogic. StdoutDebugEnabled=true